# Handle ASCII file in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, ascii, jupyter-notebook

I am just starting coding with python and I would like to extract and plot some data from an ASCII file.
I am using the following code on Jupyter Notebook to import and read the file:

```
filename = input("Insert file name: ")
openfile = open(filename,'r')
readfile = openfile.read()
print(readfile)
```

The output looks like this:

```
Insert file name: Example_File.asc

row 1

row n


row 47
    1    0.000    168.38     0.0000                                                 0.0000     0.0000                      
    2    0.020    169.42     0.0002                           0.0000               -0.0001     0.0002                      
    3    0.040    170.47     0.0006                           0.0000    -2.9038     0.0000     0.0006                      
    4    0.060    171.47     0.0002     0.0000                0.0000     1.0652    -0.0008     0.0002                      
    5    0.080    172.38     0.0007    -0.0001    -8.7283     0.0000     1.3343    -0.0006     0.0007                      
    6    0.100    173.38     0.0011     0.0000    -3.9063     0.0000     2.0894    -0.0005     0.0011                      
    7    0.120    174.33     0.0010     0.0000    -4.6450     0.0000     1.2769    -0.0010     0.0010                      
    8    0.140    175.33     0.0005     0.0000    -3.2740     0.0000     0.8283    -0.0017     0.0005                      
    9    0.160    176.38     0.0009     0.0000    -2.3600     0.0000     0.9500    -0.0017     0.0008                      
   10    0.180    177.38     0.0010    -0.0001    -8.3284     0.0000     0.9759    -0.0019     0.0010                      
   11    0.200    178.38     0.0007     0.0000    -5.7496     0.0000     0.8248    -0.0025     0.0007                      
  254    5.060    471.81     6.1288     0.0220     0.3673     0.0202    -0.0050     6.0529     6.1338                      
  255    5.080    472.77     6.7917                           0.0198    -0.0046     6.7154     6.7967                      
  256    5.100    473.69     7.3207                           0.0192    -0.0044     7.2439     7.3255                      
  257    5.120    474.71     7.9230                           0.0191    -0.0041     7.8458     7.9277                      
  258    5.140    475.69     8.2525                           0.0205    -0.0038     8.1754     8.2576                      
  259    5.167    477.38     8.8266                                     -0.0035     8.7492     8.8319
```

Then I am doing:

```
for line in readfile:
    line = line.strip()
    columns = line.split()
    c1 = float(columns[1])
    c2 = float(columns[2])
    c3 = float(columns[3])
    c4 = float(columns[4])
    c5 = float(columns[5])
    c6 = float(columns[6])
    c7 = float(columns[7])
    c8 = float(columns[8])
    c9 = float(columns[9])
    c10 = float(columns[10])
```

But I got the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-f88eb57daf30> in <module>()
      2     line = line.strip()
      3     columns = line.split()
----> 4     c1 = float(columns[1])
      5     c2 = float(columns[2])
      6     c3 = float(columns[3])

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Can someone help me with this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try anything? In how far was that no succesful. Since you are for sure not the first one with such task, in how far do other solutions not help? See [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: I was following the example explained on  https://python4astronomers.github.io/files/asciifiles.html. But on my case, the last line of the file is an empty line.

Comment: What you need to do is do create a [mcve] of the issue and make this available inside the question.

Comment: Such file will be hard to read in because it is not homogeneously structured.   You would need to locate the beginning of a section (`"row 47"`) and only read in the following lines up to the next section. You would then also need to split the columns by the number of characters, because some rows do not have data in all columns.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe those pieces of information can help you to solve your problem.

```
import pandas as pd
file_location =input("Insert file name: ")
sheet = pd.read_excel(file_location)
print(sheet["price per item"]) #instaed of c1 = float(columns[1]) you can call columns["name of the columns"]
```

[that is my excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pyl8u.png)

```
Output:
Insert file name: Retail_Sales_Data.xlsx
0      13.99
1      17.99
2      70.95
3      44.99
4      13.99
5      45.99
6      99.99
7      89.85
8       3.99
9      18.95
10      2.99
11      9.99
12    199.95
13     58.89
14    169.95
15     64.99
16     67.99
17     43.99
18    399.95
19      0.99
Name: price per item, dtype: float64
```